# Awaken effect in battle

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How does awaken works in battle? What if i have a 4/4 elemental creature that is still a land, got beaten by a 5/5 creature, will i lose the tokens or my land?

I also tried to find more information about this but couldnt find the battling system somewhere

Comment: You can read about how Combat works on [page 8 and 9 of the basic rules PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf). (It's called "combat", not "battle", which might be why you're having trouble finding mention of it.)